# Persistent cookies are not shared between Internet Explorer and Office add-in

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, office-js, office-addins

I have the [office.js add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office).
I need to show my custom HTML page in the iframe in the task pane.
I login in my custom HTML page in IE 11, but the cookies is not traveling to the task pane in the add-in.

How can we share the cookies between IE and Office add-in?

Comment: What Office application you are talking about? Is this Outlook, Word, etc? Office.js API has specific ways to preserve data inside documents or/and user settings.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  IE has a different cookie jar than the desktop add-in host.

However, if you need to prompt a login page, etc., you can use the Dialog API to prompt one in a cross-platform-compatible way.

Is there a particular scenario that is not addressed by the dialog API?